# Conversion from propositional logic to disjunctive normal form

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My question is that is there anyway by which we can prove that every propositional logic can be converted to a disjunctive normal form?

According to my approach all statements can be somehow modified to present it in the basic DNF operators by using laws such as the De Morgan's Law, Double Negation Law etc. 
But is there a hard and strong proof of this??

Comment: Use truth table.

Comment: using a truth table would be just for one particular logic. I am looking for a proof that says that all logic statements can be converted to DNF.

Comment: @user302719 Including first order logic, that is? What would the DNF be of a sentence like $\forall x\exists y(P(x)\to Q(x,y))$? DNF applies to *open* (quantifier-free) sentences or formulas. To achieve that form, you have to get rid of quantifiers by "Skolemizing".

Comment: What do you mean with "every propositional logic" ? If you consider e.g. intuitionistic propositional calculus, then Double Negation does not hold and, in general, $\to$ is not expressible in terms of $\lor$ and $\lnot$.